# import matplotlib.pyplot not working

Tags: macos, matplotlib, importerror

I am new to python and just trying to set everything up. I've tried reinstalling but still keep getting an error when I try "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", anyone know what this means?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 23, in <module>
from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 16, in <module>
import artist
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 6, in <module>
from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, TransformedPath
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 34, in <module>
from matplotlib._path import affine_transform
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install matplotlib and python2.7

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I downloaded a .dmg from python.org (I'm using OSX) and then for maplotlib I first tried to easy_install the .egg which I had downloaded from their site, then I tried a different .egg and then I tried a .dmg (although I realised later the .dmg was for 32 bit, I have 64).

So finally I uninstalled everything including python and started again except this time I used pip install matplotlib, which failed because I don't have xcode installed (no gcc) so now I am waiting for that to download.

Comment: which easy_install? and yes you need Xcode for _path.so

Comment: setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg right from their site!

Comment: Ah I meant the path to easy_install - as that could point to Apple's python - and looking at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#easy-install-from-egg to see which egg to use

Comment: Sorry but how do I find that out? :-/

Comment: in terminal type which easy_install

Comment: Ah, yep it's going to the right version.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem when installing python and matplotlib on multiple Mac OSs.  What I ended up doing was reinstalling with Python2.6 and also getting compatible packages.  It took a little while to figure out which combination works with which architecture, but eventually I got everything to run.

The matplotlib website even mentions these issuse:

"The build situation on OSX is complicated by the various places one can get the png and freetype requirements from (darwinports, fink, /usr/X11R6) and the different architectures (x86, ppc, universal) and the different OSX version (10.4 and 10.5)."